# How to override a default header defined in Razor _Layout page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm working on a .NET MVC web application and I'd like to have a consistent header among all pages on the site *except* for the landing page, where I'd like to include a sign in and registration option in the header of the page. Any ideas how to disable the default header in _Layout and instead render a separate partial view? As of now it stacks the _Layout header above my custom header. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: asp.net core and asp.net MVC4 have some pretty significant differences - which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to have a consistent header among all pages on the site except for the landing page, where I'd like to include a sign in and registration option in the header of the page.

You can try to replace the header in `_Layout.cshtml` with a sign in and registration option.

And if you want landing page don't include the header,you can create a `_Layout1.cshtml` without the header,and set it as the Layout of landing page.Add the following code to landing page can set the Layout of it.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
}
```